# @Scheduled necesita que a nivel de clase tenga un @EnableScheduling

Tags: spring-boot, schedule

Bueno tengo un servicio el cual en principio funciona. Mi duda es sencilla pero no he sido capaz de encontrar respuestas.

¿De que manera complementa @EnableScheduling a @Scheduled?

He visto bastantes ejemplos los cuales usan uno con el otro y de ahi mi duda

Un saludo !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Scheduled` se utiliza para ejecutar tareas de forma automática y periodica, esta etiqueta utiliza un soporte llamado `scheduling`.

Para habilitar dicho soporte y poder usar la anotación `@Scheduled` tenemos que agregar también la etiqueta `@EnableScheduling` en nuestra clase.

De ahí que ambas se complementen, ya que una habilita el soporte de la otra

Comment: Hasta el momento tenia solamente la anotacion @Schedule y me funcionaba. Entonces sin poner @ EnableScheduling tambien iria. Nose se me hace raro. Gracias por responder

Comment: aquí te explica un poco más el porqué una te funcionaba sin la otra [Spring-boot scheduler runs without @EnableScheduling annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43204377/spring-boot-scheduler-runs-without-enablescheduling-annotation)

Comment: Muchas gracias ahora ya lo tengo claro.